# incompatible types? - Java

Tags: java

I am getting an incompatible types error message when making this method. The method is suppose to insert the specfied element at the specfied index of the list but it does not overwrite any existing data at that location. This method does allow adding to the first index beyond the end of the list. For example, if a list had a size of 10, the index 9 is its logical end but this method allows added an element at index 10.

```
public void add(int index, java.lang.Object element)
{
   int tempCap = myArray.length;
   Object[] copyArray;
   int count;

   if(tempCap < index)
   {  
      tempCap = tempCap * 2;

      for(int i = 0; i < tempCap; i++)
      {
         copyArray[i] = myArray[i];
      }

      copyArray[index] = copyArray[element];
   }

   else
   {
      myArray[index] = myArray[element];
   }
}
```

Error message:

```
    BasicArrayList.java:53: incompatible types
    found   : java.lang.Object
    required: int
       copyArray[index] = copyArray[element];
                                       ^

    BasicArrayList.java:57: incompatible types
    found   : java.lang.Object
    required: int
        myArray[index] = myArray[element];
                                   ^
```

If the index is already occupied by data, the array should shift to make room for the new entry, assuming there is enough capacity in the array. If there isn't enough capacity, the array should be copied to a new array, and the new array should have double the capacity of the old array.

Also, I am not sure why they are incompatible. Do I need to use wrapper classes? What I am trying to say in those lines of code is "put this element, whether it be a string, int, double or char" into this slot of the array.

Comment: If `element`is an object, why are you using it like an `int`?

Comment: Think about it again... what it is element and what you mean by `copyArray[element]`?

Comment: Read the error message closely. What type do you have, and what type does the compiler want? Why do they not agree?

Comment: Yeesh. Your time would be better spent reading the source of ArrayList.java rather than trying to write your own. The amount of confusion in the above code is significant.

Comment: i've got it more or less going now, but i agree. Unfortunately that isn't the assignment.

Answer (score 2):

You never initialized the variable copyArray.

Comment: ins't it initalized when i say Object[] copyArray; ?

Comment: See my answer below, you need to declare the length of the array or provide values for the initial array.

Comment: That would declare the variable, but not initialize it.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't it be instead `myArray[index] = element`?

- And what about items already in the list at the index location and beyond? Are you supposed to swap items, or insert and move everything else to the right?
- And where do you initialize your copyArray variable? It appears to be null and to remain null throughout.
- And what happens when the method ends and the copyArray variable goes out of scope and disappears?

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses, i have edited the original post to be a bit more detailed. Sorry guys, newbie to java here, and new to stack overflow. Really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

The error you're getting is pretty self-explanatory.
You can't use anything else than int or Integer as array index.

In your code you should definitely use

```
myArray[index] = element;
```

If you would like to use Java Object as index, you may read something about `Map`s. In short, Maps are arrays, in which index can be an arbitrary type (except for primitive ones - int, float etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Array indexes are always int so you cannot say

copyArray[index] = copyArray[element];

It would fail because copyArray[element] means copyArray at the index of element which doesnt make sense

Answer (score 0):

This makes no sense to me. Aside from the fact that you are trying to use an object as an array index integer "copyArray[element]", which is illegal syntax, you are also looping from 0 to 2 * the length of an array and then trying to access that array at indexes beyond the bounds of the array. When you get the "incompatible types" error fixed by replacing that object with an int, you are going to start getting ArrayOutOfBounds exceptions whenever you call this method.

Answer (score 0):

When you are trying to access the object of an array at a given index you have to use an integer.

Right now you are using an object which does not make sense. Imagine you call this method and the way it is right now a user can call it by passing add(3, "cat").

when you reach this line:
    copyArray[index] = copyArray[element];

you are saying at copyArray[3] assign the value copyArray["cat"] ... what?????

I think what you need is:
    copyArray[index] = element;

same for the other line.

copyArray not initialized: When working with arrays you have to initialize it so that the compiler knows how much memory it should allocate to it. At the moment you have Object[] copyArray; You need to specify the length of the array you require eg. Object[] copyArray = new Object[10];

Comment: thanks, now trying to figure out why its telling me that copyArray was never initialized...thought i intialized it in that fourth line?

Comment: try: Object[] copyArray = new Object[size_of_your_array];